# Run time polymorphism with pointers in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, radix, runtime.exec, derived

I am stuck with a problem of runtime pointer assigning in C++. I have a
`base` class with 2 members thread and threads.

```
class base {

    struct base_struct {
        int a;
    };
    base_struct thread;
    std::vector<base_struct> threads;

    void fn () {}

};
```

`derived1` is derived from `base` and has the same two members (`thread` and
`threads`) but of different type.

```
class derived1 : public base {
    struct derived_struct11 : public base_struct {
        int b;
    };
    derived_struct11 thread;
    std::vector<derived_struct11> threads;

    void fn () {
        printf();
    }

};
```

`derived2` is also derived from `base` and has the same two members (`thread`
and `threads`) but of different type.

```
class derived2 : public base {
    struct derived_struct22 : public base_struct {
        int c;
    };
    derived_struct22 thread;
    std::vector<derived_struct22> threads;

    void fn () {
        printf();
    }

};
```

Only at runtime can I know whether `derived1` or `derived2` should be used. So I
did it in following way :

```
base base_obj;
derived1 derived1_obj;
derived2 derived2_obj;

base *ptr ;
```

In runtime function :

```
{
    if (condition == yes)
        ptr = &derived1_obj;

    else
        ptr = &derived2_obj;
}
```

Problem is that I can access the functions coreectly with `this` pointer. But
the value of threads (e.g: `threads.size()` is always shown as that of `base`
class.

I want to know of some better way to implement this.

Comment: This shouldn’t even compile since `base::base_struct` is `private`.

Comment: It was a bad sample. It’s very important that you post *correct* code. This makes helping **much** easier.

Answer (score 2):

The direct problem is that data members can't be virtual, so you can't override `threads` in derived classes. One solution may be to have only one `threads` in the base class, and store all struct instances in there.

However, you would then run into the problem of *slicing*: you are storing objects by values in an `std::vector<base_struct>`. This means that whenever you put an object into it, it will get copied into the vector, using the (generated) copy constructor of `base_struct`. Which means that the derived part of the original object will be sliced off, and you will only get a `base_struct` element.

To enable polymorphism you should store only pointers to `base_struct` in your vector:

```
std::vector<base_struct*> threads;
```

Another way would be to provide a virtual getter for `threads`, which you can then override in derived classes to return the desired collection. However, having several data members with the same name in a class hierarchy is IMO not a good idea. It can confuse people and result in subtle bugs. So I would prefer the first solution unless there is a very pressing reason to keep a separate collection in each class.

Comment: Thanks guys .. I do have specific reason to keep the same name members in both classes. Will try out other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One way around would be

```
base_struct* thread;
std::vector<base_struct*> threads; // <- hmmmmmmm
```

Then in your derived classes, set the base members appropriately (rather than defining two new members in the derived class - which I think is not what you are looking for anyway)